# how do draw story board to result img file

Tags: ios, swift

bottom is want result page

[image]

bottom is my story board...

[image]

bottom is my result page ...

[image]

my story board how to first image file...?

1. divider is not work... I'm try

   // saperator

   ```
      func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
      {
      let additionalSeparatorThickness = CGFloat(20)
      let additionalSeparator = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,
      cell.frame.size.height + additionalSeparatorThickness,    cell.frame.size.width, additionalSeparatorThickness))
      additionalSeparator.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
      cell.addSubview(additionalSeparator)
      }
   ```
2. background color not work
   -> storay board settings firstView and TableView background color

Comment: Please correctly format your code and take care of correct spelling and punctuation. It is a pain for native english speakers to read this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want draw the cell like the picture you post, you should not use the cell's content view directly, you should try to add another custom view in your cell content view, and set the content view's background color to `UIColor.clearColor()`, then set the custom view's `layer.cornerRadius` to `5` maybe.

Hope it can help you.